# Which metrics should a product owner look at?

Tags: sql-server, monitoring

I am the product owner for an on premise, off-the-shelf, application, which relies on a SQL Server DB.

My company outsources DB administration to a bunch of very capable folks, and tickets are issued when something is wrong. (So that I can, for example, escalate with the editor's technical teams).

However, improvement and evolution projects are my responsability, but I have a hard time figuring out if one is in order or not.

As far as performance goes, I do not follow any indicators. Without micromanaging, **is there any high-level KPIs that should be monitored by a product owner?**

Comment: *My company outsources DB administration to a bunch of very capable folks*--should not you ask those capable folks?

Comment: @SqlWorldWide The sad truth is that there is no one to actually talk to. When I have an issue, I log a ticket, and someone called "DBA-team" solves the issue.

When something is wrong on their side, and they believe it is software, they log a ticket, and I take a look. No phone number I can call or something like this...

Comment: Customer sastisfaction?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot list everything you need to monitor for a database. The biggest factor is 'It Depends'. I am going to list a few articles that might give you a starting point and from there you can adjust.

- [SQL Server Monitoring Tips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sql-server-tip-category/54/monitoring/)--I know you are not looking for how to monitor but what to monitor. If you go thru these categories and cover all you will cover most of the KPI.
- [Key metrics for SQL Server monitoring](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/sql-server-monitoring/) by Paul Gottschling
- [Server Performance and Activity Monitoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/server-performance-and-activity-monitoring?view=sql-server-ver15)